# The process could not bulk copy ... and Invalid object name errors

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have set up a transactional replication from Server A to Server B in the SQL server

Database did not exists on Server B and was created as part of the setup process - created as an empty one.
All the articles that were generated with the snapshot are in the source (Server A)
However, when checking syncronization Status, I see the error

[image]

When going to the Job History, I see the following error:

> 2024-01-03 20:59:40.781 Agent message code 20037. The process could not bulk copy into table '"dbo"."SomeTableNameDoNotKnowWhy"'.
> 2024-01-03 20:59:40.797 Category:NULL
> Source:  Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0
> Number:  208
> Message: Invalid object name 'dbo.SomeTableNameDoNotKnowWhy'.
> 2024-01-03 20:59:40.797 Category:NULL

It could be different table, and also it does not occur always.
But, anything it is, it causes the database on the server B remain empty when it occurs.

The replication set up, I am creating, I need it to be automated, that is the whole set up is triggered with the power shell scripts imitating the process that would have been taken if doing it with Sql Server Management Studio GUI.

Please, help me to understand the issues that lead to this, so I can address solution within the program.

Comment: Did this error occur during a new snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

Create the table "SomeTableNameDoNotKnowWhy" schema on the Server B and start the snapshot agent.  The error says the object name is invalid.